# How to create 2 clients

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wannt to trigger 2 clients from 1 const X with a lot of date like 50 clients and all client have username password and email.

```
const X = {
    identity: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: '123',              -----> this work
    },
    email: [
        'admin@gmail.com',
      ]
// 2 "clients var //
    identity: {
        username: 'flower',
        password: '321'              ++++++ this not work
      },
    email: [
        'flower@gmail.com'
        ]

};

const client = client(X);

client.action('');
```

Comment: it depends on how the `client` function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have an object with duplicate keys, If you create an aray of objects containing the login details, you can then do a forEach on this array to initialise the clients to an array of clients.

```
const clientDetails = [{
        identity: {
            username: 'admin',
            password: '123',
        },
        email: [
            'admin@gmail.com',
        ]
    },
    {
        identity: {
            username: 'flower',
            password: '321'
        },
        email: [
            'flower@gmail.com'
        ]
    }
]

let clients = [];


clientDetails.forEach((clientData) => {
    let thisClient = client(clientData);
    clients.push(thisClient);
    // or
    thisClient.action('')
});

// you can then access a client by using a forEach or specifically using clients[0]
```